# Firefox on OSX miscalculates CSS calc

Tags: css, macos, firefox, calc

We have created a bespoke grid system that uses `calc()` to determine column widths after deducting a fixed value for gutter ... essentially the CSS output is as follows:

```
.column{
  width: calc((((100% - 35px ) / 8) * 1) + 0px);
}
```

... for an 8-column grid's single column width.

In this instance (at this breakpoint) the **100%** width is equal to **916px**.

```
.column{
  width: calc((((916px - 35px ) / 8) * 1) + 0px);
}
```

If you do the math, the column width should now be **110.125px**; however, Firefox calculates the width to be **110.133px** (according to Firebug) or **111px** (according to Firefox web inspector). When you multiply that up again and add the gutters, you get a value of **916.064px** (or **923px**, depending on which value you trust) which is wider than the parent - the last column drops below the rest of the columns.

It's easy enough to fix by simply adjusting the gutter to 4px, but I would be very interested to know if there are any known issues with Firefox for OSX and `calc()` or if there is something wrong with the `calc()` itself.

### Edit:

I have meanwhile established that this problem occurs not only with a 5px gutter, but for all uneven numbers.

### Side note:

In case you were wondering about the seemingly unnecessary values in there, the calc() output is generated via mixin that allows us to specify only the amount of columns in the grid, the column span and the fixed gutter width as follows:

```
  $column-span: nth($column-settings, 1);
  $total-columns: nth($column-settings, 3);
  $total-gutters: ($total-columns - 1);
  $sibling-gutters: ($column-span - 1);
  width: calc((((100% - #{($gutter-setting * $total-gutters)} ) / #{$total-columns}) * #{$column-span}) + #{($gutter-setting * $sibling-gutters)});
```

Comment: Different browsers round differently, unfortunately. And on OSX even a lot of vendors resort to bad design choices to match the operating system styles. Your best bet is to use something like an existing grid framework or CSS Flexbox, if possible.

Comment: I first thought "rounding error" too, but that cannot be - how do you round up .125 to .133? The CSS rounding bugs are (to the best of my knowledge) and IE issue that will, for example, round 0.666 to 0.67 [an issue when using thirds - and we're already compensating for that in our mixin) becuase older IE rounds to 2 decimals. That is most likely not the case here.

Comment: @TylerH for reference - it is a [browser bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323735) - there is another similar issue logged and, in this case, the reporter used flexbox, but still ran into the same rounding error when using `calc()` for grid column widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this turns out to be a math bug/issue with Firefox itself - the explanation form one of the Mozilla devs:

> The reason the math doesn't work the way you expect is that it assumes
>   that Gecko represents CSS lengths with infinite (or at least very
>   high) precision.  This is not the case.  Pixel sizes are represented
>   internally as integers with a factor of 60, so 916px becomes 54960,
>   and 35px is 2100.  The first is divisible by 8, but the second is not
>   (262.5), leading to a rounding error (262). So, the calc() expression
>   is represented internally as "0.125*W - 262", so with W=54960 we get:
>   6870 - 262 = 6608 (which in CSS pixels corresponds to: 6608 / 60 =
>   110.1333333333).

A proposed work-around (by another user who has a grid system with similar math issues) would be to add a hack, at least until the issue is fixed in Firefox itself:

```
@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  .column:last-child{
    margin-right: -2px;
  }
}
```

... this negates the additional width added by the incorrect rounding. It is not very future proof, but it will get the job done; at least until the browser bug is fixed.